# Unable to sync conditional pivot table many to many relationship laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have 2 models : `Tours.php`

```
 public function includes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Included');
}
```

`Included.php`

```
public function tours()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tour');
}
```

and below code in my `TourController.php` `store` method:

```
if (isset($request->includeds) && isset($request->excludeds)) {
      $tour->includes()->sync($request->includeds, false);
      $tour->excludes()->sync($request->excludeds, false);
}
```

when i do `dd($request->includeds);` I can see the coming values from the form but unable to sync it in my pivot table `included_tour` while the code syncs `excluded_tour` without any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems to be correct. If it is still not working try the following snippet:

```
    public function includes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Included','included_tour', 'tour_id', 'included_id');
}
```